# How to run VBA script by clicking on ContentControl Checkbox in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to check all contentcontrol checkboxes by clicking contentcontrol checkbox. But how to set event to run this script by clicking on checkbox with Tag D1

```
If ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("D1")(1).Checked = True Then
   ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("D1_M1")(1).Checked = True
   ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("D1_M2")(1).Checked = True
   ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("D1_M3")(1).Checked = True
End If
If ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("D1")(1).Checked = False Then
   ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("D1_M1")(1).Checked = False
   ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("D1_M2")(1).Checked = False
   ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("D1_M3")(1).Checked = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the doucment events,

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
    If ContentControl.Title = "a1" Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Or you can add a custom event handler, like so.

In a standard module have the following.  This code will need to be run when the document is opened.

```
Public cls_CustomEventHandler As clsCustomEventHandler

Sub SetUpDocumentContentEventHandler()

Set cls_CustomEventHandler = New clsCustomEventHandler

Set cls_CustomEventHandler.wdDocumnetToListenTo = ActiveDocument

End Sub
```

and then have a class module clsCustomEventHandler, with the following code

```
Public WithEvents wdDocumnetToListenTo As Document

Private Sub wdDocumnetToListenTo_ContentControlOnExit( _
                                ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, _
                                Cancel As Boolean)

If ContentControl.Title = "a1" Then

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the 'ThisDocument' code module of the document or its template:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
With CCtrl
  If .Title = "D1" Then
    For i = 1 To 3
      ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("D1_M" & i)(1).Checked = .Checked
    Next
  End If
End With
End Sub
```