# Microsoft Word: How to enable and disable checkboxes in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

Total new to this.

On Click of Checkbox, I want to click or disable checkboxes.

Example when user click Development, It should tick YES in question and when user tick documentation it should select no.

Following is my form:
[image]
/
I enabled developer and click name tag as dev and open VBA and written follwing code:

```
Private Sub Document_New()
 If (dev.Value = True) Then
    MsgBox ("You've subscribed")
 End If
End Sub
```

Then i tried following:

```
Private Sub Document_New()
 If ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("dev")(1).Checked = True Then
   ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("codeno")(1).Checked = True
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Not able to find any output here. Legacy control is checkbox. I have given name and tags and tried to access it.

[image]

Comment: Are the mentioned controls **on a form**, as you say ("Following is my form:")? If yes, it should be nice to show us a picture of the whole form. Now, if `Development` is clicked and "Yes" has been ticked, when you check `Documentation` the `No` check box will be ticked, but you will have `Yes` also checked. You can make it `False`, but one exclude the other, you should use radio buttons instead of check boxes. Then, in the way you try, the code will work only when the document is created, or you need to run it when the necessary check box changed its value (so, use its `Change` event)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783516/how-to-run-vba-script-by-clicking-on-contentcontrol-checkbox-in-word

Comment: I forgot mentioning that you cannot save a .docx type with code inside. You must save it as 'docm type.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.new Document_New code is only executed when a new document is created based on a template where the code is written.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119724/word-checkbox-contentcontol-onchange-event

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a VBA macro you need to save the document as macro enabled one (*.docm). The following code looks good:

```
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("dev")(1).Checked = True
```

See [Word CheckBox ContentContol OnChange Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119724/word-checkbox-contentcontol-onchange-event) how to handle check box state changes.